# dealing with images on mobile application

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I am building a chatting application.

Each user can upload their profile photo and sharing with others.
What is the best approach to implement this?

I am thinking to build like..
Once a user upload their profile pic, send to the server and store it.
and then send the pic to all users device so they can see the pic.

In this case, my concern is that if the user is hundreds of people, then each device need to have hundreds of pic in their device which is going to take a huge amount of space (I guess more than 100MB) that users wouldn't like the application.

Is there any good idea or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store them, only download what you need.
I would only keep the pictures of the favourite contacts, so they load faster. For the other contacts, download them when first needed, cache them, and delete after the user exits your app.

Comment: I'd implement a fixed size LRU disk cache, so that when more than X MB of files have been downloaded, you delete the least recently used right then.  This is more efficient than just deleting on exit-  you get to it quicker, and you can keep a small cache on disk and not redownload them all next time you use the app.